# How can I create this block of HTML code using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to create this block of HTML code by using JavaScript, how can I do 
   this?

```
<a>
<span class="image"><img src="<%=request.getContextPath() 
%>/resources/build/images/cogs.jpg" alt="Profile Image" width="100"> 
</span>
<span>
<span id="timeDiv2"></span>
<span class="time" id="timeDiv3"></span>
</span>
<span class="message" id="timeDiv4">
</span>
</a>
```

Comment: createElement, innerHTML, appendChild, etc

Answer (score 2):

I have wrote it this way. No need to messy your code. Just have a look here.

```js
var aelem = createNewElement({elem:"a"});

var span =  createNewElement({elem:"span",class:"image"});
var img =  createNewElement({elem:"img",src:"https://comps.canstockphoto.co.uk/smily-picture_csp18918415.jpg"});
span.append(img);

var span1 = createNewElement({elem:"span"});
var TimeDiv2 = createNewElement({elem:"span",id:"timeDiv2"}),
timeDiv3 = createNewElement({elem:"span",id:"timeDiv3",class:"time"});
 
span1.append(TimeDiv2);
span1.append(timeDiv3);
timeDiv4 = createNewElement({elem:"span",id:"timeDiv4",class:"message"});
aelem.append(span);
aelem.append(span1);
aelem.append(timeDiv4);
console.log(aelem.outerHTML);
document.getElementById('appendHere').innerHTML = aelem.outerHTML;
function createNewElement(attr){ 
      var newElem = document.createElement(attr.elem);
      if(attr.id) newElem.setAttribute("id",attr.id);
      if(attr.class) newElem.setAttribute("class",attr.class);
      if(attr.src) newElem.setAttribute("src",attr.src);  
      if(attr.href) newElem.setAttribute("href",attr.href);
       
    //Write more attribute if you want more
      return newElem;
}
```

```html
<div id="appendHere"></div>
```

Hope it will help.
THanks

Comment: I test it but didn't work

Comment: Hi @Javareading please click on "Run code snippet" its working. If it did not work for let me know the console errors . So that I can help you on that. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
document.write( '<a>\n' );
document.write( '<span class=\"image\"><img src=\"<%=request.getContextPath() \n' );
document.write( '%>/resources/build/images/cogs.jpg\" alt=\"Profile Image\" width=\"100\"> \n' );
document.write( '</span>\n' );
document.write( '<span>\n' );
document.write( '<span id=\"timeDiv2\"></span>\n' );
document.write( '<span class=\"time\" id=\"timeDiv3\"></span>\n' );
document.write( '</span>\n' );
document.write( '<span class=\"message\" id=\"timeDiv4\">\n' );
document.write( '</span>\n' );
document.write( '</a>' );
```

Comment: This is from [Free HTML to JavaScript](http://www.andrewdavidson.com/convert-html-to-javascript/)

Comment: Doing a quick Google search would have helped with your endeavors

Comment: And how can I add this to my html file?Like this document.getElementById("div1")

Comment: You would have to create a separate .js file with any JavaScript in it and simply call that function in to the HTML file.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve writing nothing but JavaScript into an HTML file? Just trying to understand what you are trying to achieve